# Использование нестатического поля в статическом методе

Tags: java, static

Почему первый вызов `meth(x)` недопустим, в то время когда второй `meth(new A().x)` возможен, хотя передаем одно и тоже значение?

```
public class A {

int x=2;   

static void meth(int a){
    System.out.println(a);f 
}
public static final void main(String[] args){
   meth(x); //компилятор ругается на аргумент x 
   meth(new A().x);
  }
}
```

Comment: В вопросах вида «Почему возникает ошибка» нужно указывать полностью текст сообщения об ошибках.

Answer (score 2):

Статическому методу не доступны переменные уровня класса, необходимо поменять модификатор доступа у переменной х на static

```
static int x=2;
```

[К ознакомлению о видах переменных](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)

Answer (score 1):

В статическом методе можно использовать только статические переменные

Comment: То что в статическом методе должны использоваться статические члены это понятно.Вопрос в том,почему вызов meth(new A().x) допустим?Ведь аргументом так же является все тот же НЕ статический  x,только переданный не напрямую,а через создание экземпляра....